# Prevent DELETES from bypassing versioning in Amazon QLDB

Tags: amazon-qldb

Amazon QLDB allows querying the version history of a specific object by its ID. However, it also allows deleting objects. It seems like this can be used to bypass versioning by deleting and creating a new object instead of updating the object.

For example, let's say we need to track vehicle registrations by VIN.

```
INSERT INTO VehicleRegistration
<< {
    'VIN' : '1N4AL11D75C109151',
    'LicensePlateNumber' : 'LEWISR261LL'
} >>
```

Then our application can get a history of all LicensePlateNumber assignments for a VIN by querying:

```
SELECT * FROM _ql_committed_VehicleRegistration AS r
WHERE r.data.VIN = '1N4AL11D75C109151';
```

This will return all non-deleted document revisions, giving us an unforgeable history. The `history` function can be used similarly if you remember the document ID from the insert. However, if I wanted to maliciously bypass the history, I would simply delete the object and reinsert it:

```
DELETE FROM VehicleRegistration AS r WHERE VIN = '1N4AL11D75C109151';
INSERT INTO VehicleRegistration
<< {
    'VIN' : '1N4AL11D75C109151',
    'LicensePlateNumber' : 'ABC123'
} >>
```

Now there is no record that I have modified this vehicle registration, defeating the whole purpose of QLDB. The document ID of the new record will be different from the old, but QLDB won't be able to tell us that it has changed. We could use a separate system to track document IDs, but now that other system would be the authoritative one instead of QLDB. We're supposed to use QLDB to build these types of authoritative records, but the other system would have the exact same problem!

How can QLDB be used to reliably detect modifications to data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *would* be a record of the original record and its deletion in the ledger, which would be available through the history() function, as you pointed out. So there's no way to hide the bad behavior. It's a matter of hoping nobody knows to look for it.  Again, as you pointed out.

You have a couple of options here.  First, QLDB rolled-out fine-grained access control last week ([announcement here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/06/amazon-qldb-supports-iam-based-access-policy-for-partiql-queries-and-ledger-tables/)).  This would let you, say, prohibit deletes on a given table.  See [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/getting-started-standard-mode.html).

Another thing you can do is look for deletions or other suspicious activity in real-time using [streaming](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/streams.html).  You can associate your ledger with a Kinesis Data Stream.  QLDB will push every committed transaction into the stream where you can react to it using a Lambda function.

If you don't need real-time detection, you can do something with QLDB's [export feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/export-journal.html).  This feature dumps ledger blocks into S3 where you can extract and process data.  The blocks contain not just your revision data but also the PartiQL statements used to create the transaction.  You can setup an EventBridge scheduler to kick off a periodic export (say, of the day's transactions) and then churn through it to look for suspicious deletes, etc.  [This lab](https://qldb-immersionday.workshop.aws/en/lab3.html) might be helpful for that.

I think the best approach is to manage it with permissions.  Keep developers out of production or make them assume a temporary role to get limited access.